# How to call xhr in Dojo using TypeScript

Tags: dojo, typescript

I'm using Typescript (new to it), and Dojo, and I need to make an async call. This is pretty easy when you're not using TypeScript. But, the compiler is making things harder, especially because I do not allow "implicit any". I also like the lambda-style callbacks, but the compiler complained about the "implicit any" there, too. Mostly, I'm getting confused between the Deferred, and the Promise, and how to import the promise module.

Is there anybody with Typescript/Dojo experience who can tell me if I got this right? And, is there any way to improve it?

```
import xhr = require("dojo/request/xhr");

private getDataAsync(url:string, param:any):dojo.promise.Promise {
    var deferred = new Deferred();
    var options: any = {
        handleAs: 'json',
        query: {
            'param': param
        }
    };
    xhr.get(url, options).then(
        lang.hitch(this, function(data:any) {
            var returnValue = this.doSomething(data);
            deferred.resolve(returnValue);
        }),
        function(err:any) {
            deferred.reject(err, true);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Moreover, do I even need to use Dojo's xhr here? Is there something built into TypeScript that wraps XMLHTTPRequest in a browser-neutral way, the way that dojo does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `Deferred` and `Promise` classes in the `dojo.d.ts` appear to be long overdue for an update. They do not have a generic type parameter for the result type, and the `then` callbacks are just `Function`, so they capture nothing about the shape of the function. This doesn't take advantage of TypeScript 1.0, never mind 1.4.

Compare with `es6-promise.d.ts`, in which `Promise<R>` has a method `then<U>`, where `R` is the value coming out of the promise and `U` is the value produced by `then`'s resolve handler, and thus the next promise will be `Promise<U>`. So chains of operations on promises are strongly typed and everything works beautifully.

If you make similar improvements to `dojo.d.ts` and set them a pull request, they'll probably be quite grateful! :)

Comment: 4 days after I asked the questions, SitePen published an article regarding Deferred and Promise in Dojo (http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/06/understanding-deferreds-and-promises-in-dojo/). And, that led to being given the latest Dojo typings (https://github.com/SitePen/mayhem) which do incorporate Promise<R>

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something built into TypeScript that wraps XMLHTTPRequest in a browser-neutral way

No. TypeScript has *very* minimal runtime environment only for helping the compiler generate valid code (pretty much only the __extends function).

> I also like the lambda-style callbacks, but the compiler complained about the "implicit any" there, too

This is natural. The compiler does not know the result of the XHR, if you know it specify it using some interface, or you can tell the compiler that you don't want type safety and use `any` as you are doing already.

## Update 1

> I'm still stuck on the differences between dojo.promise.Promise, deferred.promise, and Deferred

Promise is a promise : https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec

Deferred is something that has a `promise` (`.promise`) as well as nice handles (`.resolve` and `.reject`) to determine the fate of the said `promise`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it makes sense for me to realize that TypeScript is focusing on typing, and not trying to be another abstraction framework. I'm trying to work the strong types as hard as I can, using generics, and also interfaces for dictionaries. Nevertheless, I'm still stuck on the differences between dojo.promise.Promise, deferred.Promise, and Deferred. It may be more of a Dojo question, but TypeScript is making it more apparent.